# Mootools ajax form response

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, submit, mootools

I'm trying to send a form with mootools and depending on the response from the php script do such or such thing. The thing is I fail to be able to use conditional statements inside of the `onComplete` part of the code.

I'm missing something really obvious probably, please help me :)

```
$('formName').addEvent('submit', function(e){
    e.stop();                      
    var req = new Request.HTML({
      url       : 'phpUrl.php',
      data      : $('formName'),
      update    : $('modify-me'),
      onComplete: function(){
            $('formName').reset();
            if($('modify-me').get('text') = "1"){
                alert("succeed");
                }else{
                alert("failure");
                }
            }  
    }).send();                    
  });
```

This was my lame attempt to use the php response in the code, but of course it didn't work.
Needless to say I'm new to all this asynchronous client-server communication stuff, but I'm really intrigued by it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning in your if statement (single =), not checking equality (==).  Change the line

```
if($('modify-me').get('text') = "1")
```

to

```
if($('modify-me').get('text') == "1")
```

Comment: Nice, +1 here.
But isn't there a way to not have to assign the response to an element before using it's value in the conditional statements?
I mean, shouldn't there be a way to discriminate from success and failure without doing that ugly thing?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - I've not used MooTools but a Google seems to suggest that onComplete will only fire once the response has completed succesfully?

Comment: completing successfully doesn't mean a particular response from the php script, that's what I fail to achieve. I would like to use the value of the response directly without adding it to an element before.

Comment: From the MooTools API: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request.HTML.  Looks like onComplete has been replaced with onSuccess, and you can access the reponseHTML (amongst other things) within the function

Comment: onSuccess is different from onComplete

Comment: Would onSuccess not be the correct event though?  The request needs to return successfully in order to inspect the returned value(s)

Comment: @Macros, you should use the parameters of your callback, onComplete: function(data){if(data == 1)}

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, maybe I'm late... I'm working on Mootools 1.2.4 for the client side and on PHP for the backend. This is the way I submit forms and get response from the server...

```
    $('myFormID').set('send', {
        noCache: true,
        onRequest: function(){
            // show some rotating loader gif...
        },
        onComplete: function(response) {
            // hide the loader gif...
            objJson = JSON.decode(response);
            if(objJson.success){
                // do your success stuff...
                alert(objJson.msg);
            } else {
                alert(objJson.msg);
            }
        },
        onFailure: function(){
            alert("Request Aborted.");
        }
    }).send();
```

In my case the form submit is triggered by a button, but could be whatever... let's look at the server side (I use PHP but any other language is good)

```
    if($somethingWentWrong){
    echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "msg" => "Check your form."));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array("success" => true, "msg" => "Data saved."));
}
```

after all the server-side checks and validations (and maybe an Update on a MySql batabase) I just return a Json array (that's whay I have a JSON.decode(response) on the client-side-earth) and then just check the "success" key to discover if the submitting succeded on the server-side-moon. I just add a small message that I display in an alert. Obviously I could use the JSON array to send back a lot more data to the client, but in this case is enough. Hope this helps and please let me know of better solutions.